# Powershell multiple function params from ValidateSet

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, validateset

I'm writing a script with PowerShell and at some point I needed to use ValidateSet  on function params. It's a very good feature, but what I need is something more than that.

For example

```
Function JustAnExample
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateSet("IPAddress","Timezone","Cluster")]
        [String]$Fields
    )

    write-host $Fields
}
```

So this code snippet allows me to choose one item from the list like that
`JustAnExample -Fields IPAddress`

and then prints it to the screen.
I wonder if there is a possibility to allow to choose multiple values and pass them to function from one Validation set like so

```
JustAnExample -Fields IPAddress Cluster
```

Maybe there is a library for that or maybe I just missed something but I really can't find a solution for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple string arguments to the `-Fields` parameter, change it to an array type (`[String[]]`):

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [ValidateSet("IPAddress","Timezone","Cluster")]
    [String[]]$Fields
)
```

And separate the arguments with `,` instead of space:

```
JustAnExample -Fields IPAddress,Cluster
```

Comment: I have one more question. Is there a way to make those selections unique? because when I run the program I am able to choose 2 or more the same values. So what I want is to make the user be able only to choose one value from the given list. 

I was reading https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15994.powershell-advanced-function-parameter-attributes.aspx#ValidateSet  
but couldn't really find anything regards to this issue

Answer (score 1):

@SokIsKedu, I had the same issue and could not find an answer. So I use the following inside the function:

```
function Test-Function {
    param (
        [ValidateSet('ValueA', 'ValueB')]
        [string[]] $TestParam
    )

    $duplicate = $TestParam | Group-Object | Where-Object -Property Count -gt 1
    if ($null -ne $duplicate) {
        throw "TestParam : The following values are duplicated: $($duplicate.Name -join ', ')"
    }

    ...
}
```

It does not prevent duplicates being passed in, but it does catch them.